# Проблема с asyncio: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'message_send' was never awaited self.tk.mainloop(n)

Tags: python, tkinter, asyncio, discord-api

Решил написать Discord бота, но вышла
проблема с библиотекой `asyncio`, которая выдаёт ошибку:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'message_send' was never awaited self.tk.mainloop(n)

Сама ошибка возникает при вызове функции `message_send()`, которая активируется после нажатия кнопки в самом клиенте.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed
import asyncio
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk

client_token = "NDE3MzQ4MjMyNDQ4OTY2NjY2.DX8JdA.rNz3HTnAIVie0MBliVewPUPRqus"
bot_prefix = "!"
Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")

    async def message_send(): # При вызове этой функции всё ломается
        message = entry_message.get()
        channel = combobox.get()
        channels = {"#channel": "394132322372419597", "#glob": "359289092917166080"}
        await client.send_message(discord.Object(id=channels[channel]), message)
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Bot client")
    root.geometry("500x400")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    entry_message = tkinter.Entry(root)
    entry_message.place(x=40, y=100, width=200, height=20)
    button_send_message = tkinter.Button(root, text='Отправить', command=message_send)
    button_send_message.place(x=140, y=140, width=100, height=25)
    combobox = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(root, values=[u"#test", u"#glob"], height=2, state='readonly')
    combobox.place(x=40, y=140, width=80)
    root.mainloop()

client.run(client_token)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ваш же вопрос [Проблема с синхронизацией python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804277/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-python)

Comment: Да, но по скольку я не могу удалить его или отредактировать, пришлось создать новый. Извиняюсь сразу за тот вопрос, подскажите, как удалить его, если знаете.

Comment: создайте *минимальный* пример кода (ошибку в несколько строк можно воспроизвести: одна строка `loop.run_until_complete(root.mainloop())` плюс строки чтоб loop, root создать). Не нужно весь код без разбора в вопрос добавлять.[mcve] Нажмите [edit].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку, ваш случай сводится к следующим строкам:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
from tkinter import Tk, Button


async def main():  # XXX BROKEN: DO NOT USE!!!
    async def coro():
        pass

    root = Tk()
    Button(text='press me', command=coro).pack()
    root.mainloop()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Если нажать на кнопку, то выводится предупреждение:

```
.../lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py:1277: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'coro' was never awaited
  self.tk.mainloop(n)
```

Здесь как минимум пара вещей неправильные:

1. Никогда, никогда не вызывайте блокирующие функции такие как `root.mainloop()` в `async` контексте
2. Создавая корутины, не забывайте их на выполнение в цикл добавлять.

Чтобы избежать блокирования asyncio цикла событий из-за `root.mainloop()` вызова, можно руками его эмулировать с помощью периодических `root.update()` вызовов. Чтобы корутину в цикл событий добавить, достаточно `asyncio.ensure_future()` вызвать (это просто на выполнение ставит, не дожидаясь окончания):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
from tkinter import Tk, Button


async def main():  
    async def coro():
        done.append(1)

    root = Tk()
    done = []
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: done.append(2))
    Button(text='press me', command=lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(coro())).pack()

    # emulate root.mainloop() without blocking the asyncio event loop
    while not done:
        root.update()  # process tkinter's events
        await asyncio.sleep(.04)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```