# Как в tkinter вставить картинку с сайта?

Tags: python, парсер, изображения, tkinter

Есть сайт wolframalpha.com , там есть API для, я отправляю запрос, получаю решение уравнения в виде картинки, вопрос: как эту картинку взять и поместить в tkinter?

Comment: Подробнее напишите свой вопрос. Как получаете своё решение в виде картинки? Исходник нужен.

Comment: http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?appid=LWLUUX-EUHYR2AKXG&input=solve+3x-7%3D11&podstate=Step-by-step%20solution любая из картинок <img>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Допустим, вам уже известен url изображения.

Ниже два примера (синхронный и асинхронный). В обоих случаях изображение скачивается из интернета в память, потом с помощью библиотеки [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) (ее нужно установить с помощью `pip install pillow`) изображение преобразовывается в формат, который понимает tkinter, потом изображение устанавливается в label.

Первое решение синхронное (графический интерфейс подвисает, пока идет загрузка), загрузка с помощью `requests`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

url = "https://www6b3.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP14531gg5c35255f535bi0000683dg2hfh4g5hh7i?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=6"

root = tk.Tk()


def load_image():
    label.config(text='Loading an image...')
    root.update()
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        label.config(text='Timeout error')
    else:
        if response.status_code != 200:
            label.config(text=f'HTTP error {response.status_code}')
        else:
            pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
            label.config(image=image, text='')

            # прикрепляем ссылку на изображение к объекту label,
            # чтобы изображение не удалил сборщик мусора
            label.image = image  


tk.Button(root, text='Load an image', command=load_image).pack()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Второй вариант с асинхронностью (Python 3.5 и выше), загрузка с помощью библиотеки [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io) (нужно установить ее с помощью `pip install aiohttp`):

```
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio
import aiohttp

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class AsyncTk(tk.Tk):
    """Асинхронная обертка для класса Tk"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

    def on_close(self):
        self.done = True

    async def updater(self):
        self.done = False
        while not self.done:
            self.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

    def mainloop(self):
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.updater())


async def fetch_image(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url)
        if response.status != 200:
            label.config(text=f'HTTP error {response.status}')
        else:
            content = await response.content.read()
            pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
            label.config(image=image, text='')
            label.image = image

    button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)


url = "https://www6b3.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP14531gg5c35255f535bi0000683dg2hfh4g5hh7i?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=6"


def load_image():
    button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    label.config(text='Loading an image...')
    asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_image(url))


root = AsyncTk()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Load an image', command=load_image)
button.pack()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Идеи для данной реализации взяты из этих ответов:

- [Use asyncio and Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896365/4752653)
- [Проблема с asyncio: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'message_send' was never awaited self.tk.mainloop(n)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804609/1365)

---

P.S. минутка саморекламы. Второй вариант (в немного другой реализации, без наследования от `Tk`) я оформил в виде модуля, выкатил на pypi. Возможно кому-то пригодится.

- Ставится через `pip install async-tkinter-loop`, см. на pypi:
  https://pypi.org/project/async-tkinter-loop/
- Проект и примеры использования (папка examples):
  https://github.com/insolor/async-tkinter-loop

Вариант с использованием модуля `async_tkinter_loop`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import aiohttp

from async_tkinter_loop import async_handler, async_mainloop
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


async def load_image(url):
    button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    label.config(text='Loading an image...')
    root.update()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url)
        if response.status != 200:
            label.config(text=f'HTTP error {response.status}')
        else:
            content = await response.content.read()
            pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
            label.config(image=image, text='')
            label.image = image

    button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)


url = "https://www6b3.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP14531gg5c35255f535bi0000683dg2hfh4g5hh7i?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=6"


root = tk.Tk()  # Объект окна создается как обычно

button = tk.Button(root, text='Load an image', command=async_handler(load_image, url))
button.pack()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

async_mainloop(root)  # Вместо стандартного `mainloop()` используется своя реализация с поддержкой асинхронности
```