# Вывод на консоль и получение ссылок

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Дело в том, что я вывожу на консоль scrolledtext с использованием Tkinter, в функции я пишу в консоль, какую ссылку просматриваю, затем обращаюсь к url через метод requests.get() и записываю содержимое страницы в файл:

```
    for k in range(len(urls)):
        console.configure(state='normal')
        console.insert('end', 'Получение страницы "'+urls[k]+'" ['+str(k+1)+' из '+str(len(urls))+']...\r\n')
        console.see('end')
        console.configure(state='disabled')
        data1 = session.get(urls[k])
        time.sleep(3)
        file2 = open('file'+str(k)+'.htm', 'w')
        file2.write(data1.text)
        file2.close()
```

Проблема в том, что приложение подвисает, в консоль ничего не пишется, а файлы сохраняются.
В чем проблема? В приоритете? То есть, функции выполняются нелинейно? Как сделать, чтобы было все по алгоритму? "Написал в консоли -> обратился к ссылке -> записал в файл"?

Comment: Уберите sleep, тогда не будет зависать. Хотя нет, будет зависать, но уже из-за того что запрос get работает синхронно, и будет блокировать графический интерфейс. Нужно или загружать в отдельном потоке или процессе, или использовать асинхронную загрузку, как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043146/1365).