# Зависает tkinter с requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, requests

Накидал небольшой GUI. Проблема в том, что Tkinter зависает при отправке запроса через библиотеку requests.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests

def rel_on():
    requests.get('http://192.168.1.100/led_on')

sc = Tk()
bt_rel = Button(text="Вкл", command=rel_on); bt_rel.pack()
sc.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если результат запроса не важен (если не нужно его отображать в графическом интерфейсе), можно просто отправку запроса делать в отдельном потоке (`print` добавлен чтобы в консоли было видно, что запрос выполнился):

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
from threading import Thread


def rel_on():
    thread = Thread(target=lambda : print(requests.get('http://192.168.1.100/led_on')), daemon=True)
    thread.start()


sc = tk.Tk()
bt_rel = tk.Button(text="Вкл", command=rel_on)
bt_rel.pack()
sc.mainloop()
```

Для более сложных случаев, если результат вызова нужно отображать в GUI, удобнее использовать асинхронный подход и [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/) вместо requests, как например во втором примере в этом ответе: [Как в tkinter вставить картинку с сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043146/1365)

---

С помощью модуля [`async_tkinter_loop`](https://github.com/insolor/async-tkinter-loop), позволяющего использовать асинхронные функции как обработчики в tkinter, и асинхронной отправки HTTP запросов с помощью [`httpx`](https://github.com/encode/httpx) (вместо `requests`):

```
import tkinter as tk

import httpx

from async_tkinter_loop import async_handler, async_mainloop


@async_handler
async def rel_on():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        await client.get("http://192.168.1.100/led_on")


sc = tk.Tk()
bt_rel = tk.Button(text="Вкл", command=rel_on)
bt_rel.pack()

async_mainloop(sc)
```

Comment: Тоже плюсанул, пригодилось, но спрошу, у вас после старта потока нет thread.join(), это допустимо? Поток сам убьется после завершения функции?

Comment: @GreenX5 join нужен, чтобы дождаться завершения потока. Поток в любом случае сам завершится, когда ему нужно, без всякого join, уже после завершения функции. Тут если добавить join, это заблокирует основной поток, и будет мешать работе mainloop (обработке событий окна), и окно подвиснет. Тут по-хорошему нужно потоки создавать с флагом `daemon=True`, иначе программа не будет завершена при закрытии окна, если будут повисшие потоки. Немного поправил ответ.

Comment: * "Поток в любом случае сам завершится, когда ему нужно" - если это поток с ограниченным временем выполнения (не с бесконечным циклом, например), в данном случае это такой поток.