# Как собрать и показать изображение из байт кода

Tags: python-3.x, img, binary

я пишу парсер для картинок и столкнулся с такой задачей, с помощью re.get(url,content) получаю байт код картинки, но скачивать я её не хочу. Вот в чем вопрос: есть ли какой-нибудь модуль или способ, чтобы без скачивания, а только из байт кода собирать и отображать картинку?

Заранее спасибо

P.S я точно не знаю как правильно называется набор символов из которого состоит изображение, поэтому зову байт-кодом

Comment: "Без скачивания" - в смысле без сохранения на жесткий диск? get в любом случае скачивает данные, но в память. Отображать можно, но это уже зависит от того какую вы библиотеку для графического интерфейса используете.

Comment: Я просто не хочу создавать дополнительные файлы, а потом их удалять, хочется чтобы взять content подставить в переменную и вывести картинку, ты сказал "Отображать можно, но это уже зависит от того какую вы библиотеку для графического интерфейса используете", а какие библиотеки позволяют это сделать?

Comment: Скорее всего любая такое позволяет сделать, но от того какую вы используете или собираетесь использовать зависит ответ. Для tkinter можете в этом ответе пример посмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043146/1365

Comment: Большое спасибо